# Re: tech questions where correct answers change over time - is there a way to show only the votes after a certain date?

Tags: support, answers, voting, accepted-answer, sorting

Note: In an act of triage, this question was retitled and edited to become a request for technical *support* instead of a *feature request* - yet still be a question to match the high quality answer that was given.  In case of a quality answer [SE urges not deleting the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) -

> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

Comment: practically activity is generally newest, especially as some folks update their answers over time

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I am aware of 'activity' (as mentioned).  However when an old answer that has been updated inadequately may have 100 times the votes of newer answers that are actually more relevant, and even if the newer answer has received more recent votes, there is no way to know it.  That is the problem whose existence motivated the proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work, but here is a method to generate such a graph to find out.

I'll illustrate with one of my own examples (anecdotal evidence, but I'm sure it applies to many more situations), [Evenly space multiple views within a container view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13075415/4751173). As of iOS 9 (5 years ago), there's a dedicated solution for this, which I wrote an answer about. I'm obviously biased, but I think that's the best/easiest one :) Of course, old answers still remained valuable for a time since developers had to support older iOS versions, but by 2018 nobody cared about iOS 8 or older anymore. Still, the highest scoring answer (yellow line), not even being the accepted answer, continued to receive more upvotes than mine (green line), perhaps because it already had so many votes that people thought it *must* be a perfect solution and simply didn't bother to scroll down. There's another answer mentioning the same solution (dark teal, the fifth line from the top) which didn't get many as many upvotes either.

[image]

You can run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1258720/upvotes-on-answers-compared?QuestionId=13075415&FromDate=2018-01-01&TillDate=2020-12-31#graph) to check the situation for other questions / timeframes.

Comment: This is a great answer, both in terms of providing a handy method which actually calculates numbers (which I never knew existed),  and in providing insight on user behavior with an example.  It's so good I now have to leave my (apparently awful) question posted.